# Using Invocable Apex in Flow Builder, can't save result?

Tags: invocable-method, flow-builder

I have a flow that will be used to convert a list view of selected records of unknown type to custom object records. When the flow launches from a list view page, there will be a screen element where the user can select Field Labels from whatever object it is, to be mapped to FirstName, LastName, and MobilePhone fields.

I'm using invocable apex, called from the flow, to return a list of field label names (of type TEXT or PHONE) that will populate a pulldown menu so the user can select the right field to be mapped.

Here's one of my invocable apex classes:

```
global with sharing class SchemaFirstName {
@InvocableMethod(label='Get First Name options for this recordId')
global static List<String> getFirstNameFieldLabels(List<String> recordIds){
    Id recordId = recordIds[0];
    List<String> firstNameLabels = new List<String>();
    Boolean needFirstList = true;
    DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = describeResult.fields.getMap();
    Set<String> fieldNames = fieldMap.keySet();
    if(fieldNames.contains('firstname')){
        firstNameLabels.add(fieldMap.get('firstname').getDescribe().getLabel());
        needFirstList = false;
    }else if(fieldNames.contains('firstname__c')){
        firstNameLabels.add(fieldMap.get('firstname__c').getDescribe().getLabel());
        needFirstList = false;
    }

    Schema.DisplayType stringType = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap().get('firstname').getDescribe().getType();

    if(needFirstList){
        for(String fieldName : fieldNames){
            if(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType() == stringType){
                if(needFirstList) firstNameLabels.add(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel());
            }
        }
    }
    return firstNameLabels;
}
```

}

The invocable apex shows up in the Flow Builder, and I can specify the input list of Ids. I have created a collection variable in the Flow, firstNameOptions, to accept the list that is returned. 
[image]

However, when I try to create the Apex module in the flow, it won't recognize the firstNameOptions variable I created.

[image]

I've searched the docs and they don't seem to get into detail about using invocable apex and handling results.

Comment: It shows up for me.Try {!firstNameOptions}

Comment: When I put in {!firstNameOptions}, it's giving me an error: `The data type of the resource you entered isn't compatible.`

Answer (score 0):

I have copied and pasted your apex code in my org. Created firstNameOptions text variable in flow and it shows up under Apex Action.Please see below screenshot.

**Deselect Allow Multiple values(Collection)**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Not sure why it's not working for me. None of my variables show up in the Search variables dropdown... How do you have them marked re: input/output? I've tried all the combinations I can think of and still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try to Deselect Allow Multiple values(Collection) checkbox under firstNameOptions

Comment: OH, just saw your comment about deselecting the collection. Why? Isn't a list<string> considered a collection?

Comment: OK, now I have the values in the variable... I just need to figure out how to get them into my choices for the picklist... :)